# Building RNN from scratch in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build RNN from scratch using pytorch and I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/dair-ai/building-rnns-is-fun-with-pytorch-and-google-colab-3903ea9a3a79) to build it.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class BasicRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        super(BasicRNN, self).__init__()

        self.Wx = torch.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons) # n_inputs X n_neurons
        self.Wy = torch.randn(n_neurons, n_neurons) # n_neurons X n_neurons

        self.b = torch.zeros(1, n_neurons) # 1 X n_neurons

    def forward(self, X0, X1):
        self.Y0 = torch.tanh(torch.mm(X0, self.Wx) + self.b) # batch_size X n_neurons

        self.Y1 = torch.tanh(torch.mm(self.Y0, self.Wy) +
                            torch.mm(X1, self.Wx) + self.b) # batch_size X n_neurons

        return self.Y0, self.Y1


class CleanBasicRNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, batch_size, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        super(CleanBasicRNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = BasicRNN(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.hx = torch.randn(batch_size, n_neurons) # initialize hidden state

    def forward(self, X):
        output = []

        # for each time step
        for i in range(2):
            self.hx = self.rnn(X[i], self.hx)
            output.append(self.hx)

        return output, self.hx


FIXED_BATCH_SIZE = 4 # our batch size is fixed for now
N_INPUT = 3
N_NEURONS = 5

X_batch = torch.tensor([[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], 
                         [6,7,8], [9,0,1]],
                        [[9,8,7], [0,0,0], 
                         [6,5,4], [3,2,1]]
                       ], dtype = torch.float) # X0 and X1

model = CleanBasicRNN(FIXED_BATCH_SIZE,N_INPUT,N_NEURONS)

a1,a2 = model(X_batch)
```

Running this code returns this error

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 5], m2: [3 x 5] at /pytorch/..

After some digging I found this error happens when passing the hidden states to the `BasicRNN` model

```
N_INPUT = 3 # number of features in input
N_NEURONS = 5 # number of units in layer
X0_batch = torch.tensor([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], 
                         [6,7,8], [9,0,1]],
                        dtype = torch.float) #t=0 => 4 X 3

X1_batch = torch.tensor([[9,8,7], [0,0,0], 
                         [6,5,4], [3,2,1]],
                        dtype = torch.float) #t=1 => 4 X 3

test_model = BasicRNN(N_INPUT,N_NEURONS)
a1,a2 = test_model(X0_batch,X1_batch)
a1,a2 = test_model(X0_batch,torch.randn(1,N_NEURONS)) # THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
```

What is happening in the hidden states and How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the tutorial is wrong: `torch.mm(X1, self.Wx)` multiplies a `3 x 5` and a `4 x 5` tensor, which doesn't work. Even if you make it work by rewriting as `torch.mm(self.Wx, X1.t())`, you expect it to output a `4 x 5` tensor, but the result is a `4 x 3` tensor.

Answer (score 1):

The `BasicRNN` is not an implementation of an RNN cell, but rather the full RNN fixed for two time steps. It is depicted in the image of the tutorial:

[image: BasicRNN]

Where `Y0`, the first time step, does not include the previous hidden state (technically zero) and `Y0` is also `h0`, which is then used for the second time step, `Y1` or `h1`.

An RNN cell is one of the time steps in isolation, particularly the second one, as it should include the hidden state of the previous time step.

The next hidden state is calculate as described in the [`nn.RNNCell` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.RNNCell):

[image: RNNCell formula]

In your `BasicRNN` there is only one bias term, but you still have a weight `Wx` for the input and the weight `Wy` for the hidden state, which should probably be called `Wh` instead. As for the forward method, its arguments become the input and the previous hidden state, instead of being two inputs at different time steps. This also means that you only have one calculation, corresponding to the formula of the `nn.RNNCell`, which was the calculation for the `Y1`, except that it uses the hidden state that was passed to the forward method.

```py
class BasicRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        super(BasicRNN, self).__init__()

        self.Wx = torch.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons) # n_inputs X n_neurons
        self.Wh = torch.randn(n_neurons, n_neurons) # n_neurons X n_neurons

        self.b = torch.zeros(1, n_neurons) # 1 X n_neurons

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        return torch.tanh(torch.mm(x, self.Wx) + torch.mm(hidden, self.Wh) + self.b)
```

In the tutorial, they opted to use `nn.RNNCell` directly instead of implementing the cell.

Note: The terms of the matrix multiplications are in a different order, because the weights are usually transposed in comparison to your weights and the formula assumes the input and hidden state to be vectors (not batches). Technically, the batched inputs and hidden states would have to be transposed, and the output would be transposed back for it to work with the batches. It's easier to just use the transposed the weight, as the result is the same due to the transpose property of the matrix multiplication:

[image: Matrix Multiplication Transpose Property]